# Avoid signed by unsigned integer division

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

I ran into this problem when I was doing the following code:

```
int average = std::accumulate(vi.begin(), vi.end(), 0) / vi.size();
```

Without an `int` cast on `vi.size()` the output is garbage, because `size()` returns an unsigned integer.

I never would've figured this out if I hadn't googled a reference for vector. Is there a way of avoiding this trap? With `-Wall` and `-pedantic`, gcc doesn't seem to give any warnings about this kind of division.

Comment: You should also be careful about overflow in that code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc` has the `-Wconversion` flag, which for this case warns me:

```
warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’   may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     int average = std::accumulate(vi.begin(), vi.end(), 0) / vi.size();
                                                            ^
```

The [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says:

> -Wconversion
>
> > Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes conversions between real and integer, like abs (x) when x is double; conversions between signed and unsigned, like unsigned ui = -1; and conversions to smaller types, like sqrtf (M_PI). Do not warn for explicit casts like abs ((int) x) and ui = (unsigned) -1, or if the value is not changed by the conversion like in abs (2.0). Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers can be disabled by using -Wno-sign-conversion.
> >
> > For C++, also warn for confusing overload resolution for user-defined conversions; and conversions that never use a type conversion operator: conversions to void, the same type, a base class or a reference to them. Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

Comment: Is there any equivalent for this flag for Visual Studio compiler?